# Discord JavaScript bot failing to kick a user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

While writing a program for bot to kick a specific user through his id, the bot doesn't kick them out.

Here's my code

```
if(CMD_NAME === 'kick')
{
  //message.channel.send('Kicking... none for now.')
  if (!message.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS'))
    return message.reply('You do not have permissions to use that command');
  
    if (args.length === 0)
    return message.reply('Please provide an ID');

  console.log(args[0])
  //console.log(client.users.cache.find(user => user.id === args[0]))

  const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
  //message.channel.send(member)

  if (member === true) 
  {
    member
      .kick()
      .then((member) => message.channel.send(`${member} was kicked.`))
      .catch((err) => message.channel.send('I cannot kick that user :('));
  } 
  else
  {
    message.channel.send('That member was not found');
  }
}
```

In console, the bot clearly detects the id, but failing to kick him/her out.
Result comes as

> That member was not found

Comment: Does this help - https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/discord.js+kick+or+ban+member+command

Comment: Also, have you resolved your member properly?

Comment: what result to you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line makes no sense

```js
if (member === true)
```

`GuildMember`s are not booleans. Simply removing `=== true` will work

```js
if (member)
```

A `GuildMember` is a truthy value, but not `true` itself.

Comment: it still gives the same result

Comment: What result? You failed to tell us the result

Comment: sorry... the result is 'That member was not found'

Comment: Well simply the member isn't found in the cache

Comment: Try fetching instead (note it is a promise which must be awaited)





















`const member = await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0])`

Comment: it tells await is only valid in async function

Comment: make sure it is an async callback: `client.on("message", async message =>`

Comment: note it says `async` before `message`

Answer (score 0):

Change `if (member === true)` to `if (member)` and it should work correctly.

Comment: same result comes